# Adding a row after the current active one by click on button (div) outside of the current table

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a table with let's say 5 tr's and in every tr there's a few td's with inputs in them.

I've also got two buttons: add and delete a row. These buttons are in a separate div beneath the entire table, so those buttons are not on every row like i see some people place them.

I'm trying to make it so that when the user is in an input on row 2 of 5 rows and when he/she presses the 'add' button, jQuery will insert a row after the row they are on (so after row 2).

My problem is that i do not know on what row the user is with the cursor (in an input field) when he/she presses the add button. Because pressing the button makes the focus go off of the input and therefor i have no idea on what row they were.

I'm thinking of using an invisible checkbox or an addClass 'active' on every row which turns on when the user places the cursor in an input on that row and insert a row after the one with this checkbox turned on.

But, I'm curious if anyone else has any useful ideas for doing this more efficient or better?

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden input field in body and on each click on tr's input, update row number in this hidden field, and on click of add button, take value from hidden field, and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Harish,

I've thought about doing that, but i didn't want to go that way. Had that before and i found it a bit too much.

So for reference for anyone else maybe finding this post and wanting maybe an idea: i've solved it by adding a class 'act' to the currently focussed input and upon clicking on the buttons outside of the table i'm able to find the currently focussed input by selecting the input with that class.

Hope this might help someone else in the future!